# String containing address of value -> pointer for that value

Tags: c++

So I have a string that holds an address to another variable, and I want to cast that address to an actual pointer so I can edit the value at that address.

So, I basically want to do the opposite of this.

```
int value = 10;
auto address = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&value);
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::hex << address;
std::string strAddr (ss.str());
std::cout << "Address of value = " << strAddr << std::endl; // just append "0x" to start if you want to format it like hex
```

Comment: You are aware that serialized pointers aren't stable outside a single process context?

Comment: Like @πάνταῥεῖ has stated, the address is meaningless outside of the current process - furthermore if the address points to a variable on the stack, it becomes invalid when you leave its scope.

Comment: Beware of taking pointers to local variable or the addresses of local variables.

Comment: What makes you think that the conversion to a string is reversible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reverse process:

```
const std::string address_as_text = "0x12345678";
unsigned int address_as_number = 0U;
std::istringstream addr_stream(address_as_text);
addr_stream >> hex >> address_as_number;
int * pointer_to_int = (int *) address_as_number;
int value_from_memory = *pointer_to_int;
```

Comment: As long as it is a `std::string` variable, the source does not matter.

Comment: If this answer was helpful, please click on the check mark.